# Leetcode problem: Remove Duplicates from Sorted Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
Example :

Input: nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4]
Output: 5, nums = [0,1,2,3,4,_,_,_,_,_]
Explanation: Your function should return k = 5, with the first five elements of nums 
             being 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 respectively.
It does not matter what you leave beyond the returned k (hence they are underscores).
```

My code to solve this problem is

```
 var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
 const non_duplicates = [];

for (let i=0;i<=nums.length-1;i++){
    if(!(non_duplicates.includes(nums[i]))){
        non_duplicates.push(nums[i]);
       
    }
     
}
console.log(non_duplicates)
return non_duplicates.length;

};
```

That ***console.log(non_duplicates)*** displays correct output in stdOut. But when I return ***non_duplictes*** it prints empty array in output. And when I return ***non_duplictes.length*** it returns some array rather than the length of that array.

**Please don't suggest any other method to solve this problem. Just tell what is wrong with this code**

[You can see that problem here](https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-array/)

Comment: why don't you use the hint tab on the leetcode page?

Comment: @jsotola can you please tell what is wrong with my code?

Comment: I think you need to do 2 things: 1) modify the `nums` input array in place and 2) return the number of non-duplicates as the return value of the function. So, after calling your function, the return value would be 5 and the first 5 values in the passed-in array would be 0,1,2,3,4 (the value of the others doesn't matter).

Comment: Your code works fine. Its your return that is the problem. You are returning the length of the array and not the array itself. So just remove .length from the return

Comment: @imvain2 No, if you read the Leetcode JS answer template, the return value is a number, while the input/output parameter `nums` is an array of numbers. The problem also tells you: "Return k after placing the final result in the first k slots of nums."

Comment: @imvain2 have already tried. when I return array itself an empty array gets printed is output section.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution doesn't modify the array inplace. That's the first problem.
A bigger problem is that your algorithm is with O(N^2) time complexity, due to `includes` call and given that "1 <= nums.length <= 3 * 104" your solution would be incredibly slow if it ever passes the tests.

The goal is to find a linear solution of the problem. One possible solution would be:

```
var removeDuplicates = function(nums) {
    let j = 0;
    for (let i = 1, len = nums.length; i < len; i++) {
        if (nums[i] !== nums[j]) {
            nums[++j] = nums[i];
        }
    }
    
    return j + 1;    
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the correct value but you are not overwriting the `nums` array with the non-duplicate values.

After calling your function, the return value should be 5 and the first 5 values in the passed-in `nums` array should be 0,1,2,3,4 (the value of the others doesn't matter).

Simplest solution that's compatible with your attempted solution is:

1. copy the values from non_duplicates into nums
2. return non_duplicates.length.

Here's a simple example of how to do this:

```
var removeDuplicates = function (nums) {
  const non_duplicates = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (!non_duplicates.includes(nums[i])) {
      non_duplicates.push(nums[i]);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < non_duplicates.length; i++) {
    nums[i] = non_duplicates[i];
  }

  return non_duplicates.length;
};
```

Note: this is not the most efficient solution, and efficiency becomes important with the medium to hard Leetcode challenges, but it's simple, close to your intended solution, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [`Set()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) Object.

```js
let nums = [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4];

const uniqueNums = [...new Set(nums)];

console.log(uniqueNums.length, uniqueNums);
```